# 'analytics' is not defined error with Upload data script with GA Management API

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to upload some custom data into GA with Python. It's the first I'm doing this so I'm not sure about nothing.

I've build the following script based on the example from the [doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/uploadData). When running it I have the following error :

```
  File "import.py", line 50, in <module>
    daily_upload = analytics.management().uploads().uploadData(
NameError: name 'analytics' is not defined
```

Here is my code :

```
import argparse

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

import httplib2
import urllib2 
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools



def get_service(api_name, api_version, scope, key_file_location,
                service_account_email):
  """Get a service that communicates to a Google API.

  Args:
    api_name: The name of the api to connect to.
    api_version: The api version to connect to.
    scope: A list auth scopes to authorize for the application.
    key_file_location: The path to a valid service account p12 key file.
    service_account_email: The service account email address.

  Returns:
    A service that is connected to the specified API.
  """

  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
    service_account_email, key_file_location, scopes=scope)

  http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  service = build(api_name, api_version, http=http)

  return service

from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
try:
  media = MediaFileUpload('mycsv.csv',
                          mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                          resumable=False)
  daily_upload = analytics.management().uploads().uploadData(
      accountId='XXXXXX',
      webPropertyId='XXXXXXX',
      customDataSourceId='XXXXXXXXXX',
      media_body=media).execute()

except TypeError, error:
  # Handle errors in constructing a query.
  print 'There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error



def main():
  # Define the auth scopes to request.
  scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics']

  # Use the developer console and replace the values with your
  # service account email and relative location of your key file.
  service_account_email = 'XXXXXX@XXXXXX'
  key_file_location = 'XXXXXXXXXX.p12'

  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service = get_service('analytics', 'v3', scope, key_file_location,
    service_account_email)
  profile = get_first_profile_id(service)
  print_results(get_results(service, profile))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

If my code isn't clear or show some other obvious mistake different from the one I'm questioning please be comprehensive I'm learning !

Edit: I've checked in my API Manager the Analytics API is well enable

Comment: In that doc there is "This code assumes you have an authorized Analytics service object."

Comment: I've kind of done this following the doc here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-py and this part is working. I guess I don't understand something but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. It is a simple block alignement issue. I needed to align this part :

```
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
try:
  media = MediaFileUpload('mycsv.csv',
                          mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                          resumable=False)
  daily_upload = analytics.management().uploads().uploadData(
      accountId='XXXXXX',
      webPropertyId='XXXXXXX',
      customDataSourceId='XXXXXXXXXX',
      media_body=media).execute()

except TypeError, error:
  # Handle errors in constructing a query.
  print 'There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error
```

with the first part !